# How to make a histogram with character variables in R

Tags: r, histogram

I know there're a few entries that discuss this issue but I haven't been able to work out my particular case with them so here goes my question.

I have two columns with character values for which I need to plot an histogram. My original code was this:

```
hist(airbnb, "host_is_superhost", "host_identity_verified")
```

> Error in hist.default(airbnb, "host_is_superhost", "host_identity_verified") :
> 'x' must be numeric

I tried changing both variables to numeric characters like this, but I got another error that I couldn't figure out:

```
variable_num1 <- as.numeric("host_is_superhost")
variable_num2 <- as.numeric("host_identity_verified")
```

> Warning message:
> NAs introduced by coercion
> variable_num2 <- as.numeric("host_identity_verified")
> Warning message:
> NAs introduced by coercion
> hist(airbnb, "variable_num1", "variable_num2")

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(airbnb)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(airbnb, 20))`.

Comment: just edited the question Rui. Thanks!